# importxml of url with Hebrew returns in encoding other than UTF-8 that chrome doesn't recognize

Tags: google-sheets, encoding, google-sheets-formula

For example, in the [dummy spreadsheet (tab 'desired outcome')](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RhrNHwmTKvPXvShJzR0clfZ9-pVd6DBUlD7nhtKM8yY/edit#gid=642122093&range=H5), under "Link 1" you will see this URL:

http://www.promotion-il.co.il/service/%5DE%5E4%5D9%5E5-%5E8%5D9%5D7-%5D7%5E9%5DE%5DC%5D9-%5DC%5E2%5E1%5E7%5D9%5DD/

However, the actual URL in UTF-8 is:

http://www.promotion-il.co.il/service/%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A5-%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%97-%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%99-%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9D/

The actual URL string that contains Hebrew is:

[http://www.promotion-il.co.il/service/מפיץ-ריח-חשמלי-לעסקים/](http://www.promotion-il.co.il/service/%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A5-%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%97-%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%99-%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9D/)

I will also add that the same URL has returned with a proper UTF-8 encoding for other blog posts. (See [second example in the same tab](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RhrNHwmTKvPXvShJzR0clfZ9-pVd6DBUlD7nhtKM8yY/edit#gid=642122093&range=H7)).

Why is it happening?
How can it be fixed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like that the link which is fine, is using the UTF-8 version of the URL in the page, but the other it is using the Hebrew version and when using IMPORTXML the result is not parsed correctly. Have you considered using apps script to solve this issue?

Comment: I actually already have a solution for converting Hebrew in URLs into UTF-8 encoding. The issue is that IMPORTXML imports the wrongly parsed link, not the one with the hebrew.

Comment: Can you check if this happens with more links in Hebrew?

Comment: It does, occasionally. Might be related to the site where the link is published, but not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with eventually:
I saw that for the imported urls - in order to fix a broken url 2 repalcements were needed:

1. 5D --> D7%9
2. 5E --> D7%A

I used this formula in a separate column to achieve it:

```
==ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE((<COLUMN WITH IMPORTED URLS HERE>),"5D","D7%9"),"5E","D7%A"))
```